# How do I simplify this expression a $4\times 2^{k-1}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I know this can be very simple for many of you, I know the answer is $2^{k+1}$ but I don't know how that's the answer. and where can I see the rules for simplifying this kind of expressions.

Answer (score 2):

$4\times 2^{k-1} = 2^2\times 2^{k-1} = 2^{2+(k-1)} = 2^{k+1}$

Comment: I totally understand it now, Thank you so much!